# Unit test for Asp.Net 5 MVC without running Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am new to Asp.net 5 and have a question regarding unit test.

The class I am going to test is as follow

```
public class TargetController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITargetRepository _targetRepository;
    public TargetController(ITargetRepository targetRepository)
    {
        this._targetRepository = targetRepository;
    }
    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return this.View("Index");
    }
}
```

where the TargetRepository  is

```
public class TargetRepository : ITargetRepository
{
    private readonly TargetContext _context;

    public TargetRepository(TargetContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }
}
```

and the TargetContext is

```
public class TargetContext : DbContext
{

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string connectionString = Startup.Configuration["Data:TargetContextConnection"];
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

The test code is

```
public class TargetControllerTests
{
    private readonly TargetController _controller;

    public TargetControllerTests()
    {
        this._controller = new TargetController(new TargetRepository(new TargetContext()));
    }

    [Fact()]
    public void IndexActionResultTest()
    {
        ViewResult vr = this._controller.Index() as ViewResult;
        Assert.NotNull(vr);
        Assert.Equal("Index", vr.ViewName);
    }
}
```

The problem is as follow. In TargetContext, I used

```
Startup.Configuration["Data:TargetContextConnection"]
```

to get the database connection string, which is defined in Startup.cs file. Since I just test the Index function in TargetController, I did not run Startup.cs. As a result, I got NULLException for Startup.Configuration. I am wondering how can I solve this problem and run my unit test.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to mock your database context as well. Unit test should never be using 'real' data from a database.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. Then I think I need to create connection string for my test, rather than using the config in my target project.

Comment: What mocking framework are you using?

Comment: I have no idea about mocking framework since I am new to this area and learning at the moment. If you have any suggestion, it is appreciated.

Comment: I use [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) but there are lots you can choose from.

Comment: Thank you, Stephen. I will have a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Moq, your test should look like this:

```
public class TargetControllerTests
{

    private readonly Mock<ITargetRepository> _targetRepository;
    private readonly TargetController _controller;

    public TargetControllerTests()
    {
        _targetRepository = new Mock<ITargetRepository>();
        this._controller = new TargetController(_targetRepository.Object);
    }

    [Fact()]
    public void IndexActionResultTest()
    {
        ViewResult vr = this._controller.Index() as ViewResult;
        Assert.NotNull(vr);
        Assert.Equal("Index", vr.ViewName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, andreasnico. Thank you for your answer. I have a problem when I use moq in my project. I asked the question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36102010/using-moq-in-asp-net-5-with-dnx50. Can you please help to see how I can solve the problem? Thank you.

Comment: @Ben I've checked it, and I'm sorry I do not know about that problem